# Store Report names in an Interface , Enum , or as constant inside the report handler class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, reporting-services, jasper-reports, constants

For every Report I have a special handler class for that report currently I store the report name as a private constant inside the handler class.

I use the report name as a key to get this report specific configuration from the reports configuration file.

I thought about changing this and store all the report names in an enum , the other approach I have in mind is to use the fully qualified name of the handler class as the key in the configuration file.

I need to know which approach is better :
Interface , Enum , Handler class constant or use the class name as a key in the configuration file instead of the report name

Please Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like using enums and have used them often. You have to store the data somewhere, why not put it where everyone can find it!

Do something like this:

```
public enum Report {
    SALES("Sale Report", "select * from some_view"),
    PROFIT("Profit Report", "select * from some_other_view");

    final String reportName;
    final String sql;

    private Report(String reportName, String sql) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    public String getReportName() {
        return reportName;
    }

    public String getSql() {
        return sql;
    }
}
```

Comment: This what I thought about but is it practical for storing a list that will be more than one hundred report.

Comment: Hmmm, that is a lot for an enum. With *that* many you might be better to save them into a database as load them. However, the fact remains that you need to store it somewhere and it's easier to maintain the enums - just type it in. You can add and remove fields as you like, not involve DBAs with table changes, you have control. I would consider still using enums even for 100 reports. But you have to consider who will maintain the data. If users create/edit report options, use a database and web interface. Good luck.

Comment: I Agree with you I don't see a better/simple approach than Enums
and There is no create/edit report option available for users
Thanks for your time/quick answer

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an inheritance hierarchy; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108081/inheritance-or-enum).  That is, have a `SaleReport` class that inherits from your base `Report` class, and a `ProfitReport` class that inherits from `Report`, etc.  Have a different subclass for each different report type, and a common base report class.